# Simple Javascript Validation not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do the following:

HTML Code

```
<body>
    <form name="myform">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="first_name"></td>
            <td><p id="demo"></p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" id="Submit" onclick="validate()"></td>
        </tr>
    </form></body>
```

JavaScript Code

```
<script>
    function validate(){

        var fname = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
        if(fname.length>0){
            document.getElementById("demo").value="";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("demo").value="Name field empty";
        }
    }
    </script>
```

when I click the button with the empty First name field it should assign "name field empty" but it does not do that even though the control of the script goes there but it does not print anything in the <p> tag.

Comment: You need to use `.innerHTML` not `.value` Paragraphs tags have inner content, not a value. You might want to add `event.preventDefault()` to stop the form submitting

Comment: … and you’ll need to prevent your form from getting submitted if validation fails.

Comment: @NewToJS: Thanx it worked.

Comment: @Ven very welcome, it's a simple mistake to make.

Comment: @CBroe: Thanx I will keep that in mind

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this instead :D

```
<script>
    function validate(){

        var fname = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
        if(fname!=""){
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Name field empty";
        }
    }
    </script>
```

You wanna check if the field is empty or not so in this case the fname is enough to use all along. If the variable fname (which is the first_name field's value) is not empty then it proceed the statement that will set the  HTML content of "demo" to "" with `.innerHTML`. The `.value` you used has nothing to do with the display HTML content relating to demo :D. I hope my English is not that bad for you to understand this.

Comment: **You should try this** doesn't explain the issue making this a bad answer.

Comment: Ouch :S kinda new to this so, I'll fix this soon

Comment: Pointless fixing it, the issue has been solved within the comments of the OP's question.